# How to install plotrix package on R?

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I had a problem by installing `plotrix` package on R like the following:

```
> install.packages("plotrix")
Installing package into ‘/home/agn/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘plotrix’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

How could I update R to the latest version (3.6.6)?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- *OS: Ubuntu 16.04*
- *R version: 3.4.4*

Comment: Reinstall R from CRAN, then install the package? Or install the package version that is compatible with your current R version.

Comment: @zx8754 I did it before but the problem is remaining

Comment: What do you mean "I did it before"?

Comment: @zx8754 I did reinstall the R with [this instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2)